# How to fix AVI index error

Tags: 10.10, gmplayer, vlc, avi

I try to open an AVI file.

1. The first software I tried is VLC
   media player. It reports some error
   about AVI index:

   > This AVI file is broken. Seeking will
   >   not work correctly. Do you want to try
   >   to fix it? 
   >   This might take a long time.

   I chose yes, and it began fixing AVI
   index and existed when the repair
   progress bar reaches 20% or so. Then
   the video started playing and
   stopped much earlier than when it is
   supposed to finish.
2. Next I tried to open it in Totem Movie
   Player, which also stopped earlier
   at the same place as in VLC player.
3. I tried to play it in GMplayer. Now the
   entire AVI file can be played from
   start to finish, but it is
   impossible to drag playing progress
   bar while it was possible in VLC
   player and Totem player.
4. I heard that Avidemux can fix AVI
   index error, but later discovered it even failed to open the
   AVI file before it could try to fix the error.

So I was wondering how I can fix the AVI index error, or at least drag the playing progress bar in GMplayer?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5):

I was able to restore a broken avi index using this

```
$ mencoder -forceidx input.avi -o output.avi -oac copy -ovc copy
```

Source: http://compbrain.net/archives/18

However, the file was playable in VLC before. After repairing the index, VLC's warning just disappeared.

Comment: This is great solution, but in some cases it will only fix several minutes (seconds). To fix the whole file, you need a better solution.